# Nested Threads (Tasks) Timing Out Prematurely

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I have the following code, what it does I don't believe is important, but I'm getting strange behavior.

When I run just the months on separate threads, it runs fine(how it is below), but when I multi-thread the years(uncomment the tasks), it will timeout every time. The timeout is set for 5 minutes for months/20 minutes for years and it will timeout within a minute.

Is there a known reason for this behavior? Am I missing something simple?

```
    public List<PotentialBillingYearItem> GeneratePotentialBillingByYear()
    {
        var years = new List<PotentialBillingYearItem>();
        //var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var startYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - 10, 1, 1);
        var range = new DateRange(startYear, DateTime.Today.LastDayOfMonth());

        for (var i = range.Start; i <= range.End; i = i.AddYears(1))
        {
            var yearDate = i;
            //tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            //{
                years.Add(new PotentialBillingYearItem
                {
                    Total = GeneratePotentialBillingMonths(new PotentialBillingParameters { Year = yearDate.Year }).Average(s => s.Total),
                    Date = yearDate
                });
            //}));
        }

        //Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

        return years;
    }

    public List<PotentialBillingItem> GeneratePotentialBillingMonths(PotentialBillingParameters Parameters)
    {
        var items = new List<PotentialBillingItem>();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var year = new DateTime(Parameters.Year, 1, 1);
        var range = new DateRange(year, year.LastDayOfYear());

        range.Start = range.Start == range.End ? DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfYear() : range.Start.FirstDayOfMonth();

        if (range.End > DateTime.Today) range.End = DateTime.Today.LastDayOfMonth();

        for (var i = range.Start; i <= range.End; i = i.AddMonths(1))
        {
            var firstDayOfMonth = i;
            var lastDayOfMonth = i.LastDayOfMonth();
            var monthRange = new DateRange(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth);
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var db = new AlbionConnection())
                {

                    var invoices = GetInvoices(lastDayOfMonth);

                    var timeslipSets = GetTimeslipSets();

                    var item = new PotentialBillingItem
                    {
                        Date = firstDayOfMonth,
                        PostedInvoices = CalculateInvoiceTotals(invoices.Where(w => w.post_date <= lastDayOfMonth), monthRange),
                        UnpostedInvoices = CalculateInvoiceTotals(invoices.Where(w => w.post_date == null || w.post_date > lastDayOfMonth), monthRange),
                        OutstandingDrafts = CalculateOutstandingDraftTotals(timeslipSets)
                    };

                    items.Add(item);
                }
            }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: 1) You **really** don't want to do it this way with an unlimited number of threads hitting your database. Use `Parallel.` and set a maximum degrees of concurrency; 2) `List<>` is not thread safe. See also PLINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good call on `List<>`, I never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider pre-allocating a bigger number of threadpool threads. The threadpool is very slow to allocate new threads. The code below task only 10 seconds (the theoretical minimum) to run setting the minimum number of threadpool threads to 2.5k, but commenting out the SetMinThreads makes it take over 1:30 seconds.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2500, 10);
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    RunTasksOutter(10);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished in {sw.Elapsed}");
}

public static void RunTasksOutter(int num) => Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, num).Select(x => Task.Run(() => RunTasksInner(10))).ToArray());
public static void RunTasksInner(int num) => Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, num).Select(x => Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000))).ToArray());
```

You could also be running out of threadpool threads. Per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx one of the times to not use the threadpool (which is used by tasks) is:

> You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from starting.

Since IO is being done on these threads maybe consider replacing them with async code or starting them with the LongRunning option? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But why would it be timing out within a minute?

Comment: The threadpool adds a 500ms delay before any new thread is created. The pool only starts with 8 threads. The documentations specifically says: You need to start a number of threads in a very short time, to execute tasks that last a second or more. As part of its thread management strategy, the thread pool delays before creating threads. Therefore, when a number of tasks are queued in a short period of time, there can be a significant delay before all the tasks are started.

Comment: I understand that, but when it hits the `GeneratePotentialBillingByYear()`, it fails about 32 seconds into the function.

Comment: I missed that part of your question. Since an exception isn't being thrown from your sub task generator I've got no idea:-/

Comment: Ps Your call to years.add isn't thread safe when using Task.Run

Comment: Yeah, I switched it to a ConcurrentBag. Thanks